# dplyr::left_join produce NA values for new joined columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two tables I wish to `left_join` through the `dplyr` package. The issue is that is produces `NA` values for all new columns (the ones I'm after).

As you can see below, the `left_join` procudes `NA` values for the new column of `Incep.Price` and `DayCounter`. Why does this happen, and how can this be resolved?

Update: Thanks to @akrun, using `left_join(Avanza.XML, checkpoint, by = c('Firm' = 'Firm'))` solves the issue and the columns are joined correctly.

However the warning message is sitll the same, could someone explain this behaviour? Why one must in this case explicitly specify the `join` columns, or otherwise produce `NA` values?

```
> head(Avanza.XML)
                      Firm Gain.Month.1 Last.Price Vol.Month.1
1     Stockwik Förvaltning       131.25      0.074   131264420
2                 Novestra        37.14      7.200      605330
3       Bactiguard Holding        29.55     14.250     2815572
4              MSC Group B        20.87      3.070      671855
5 NeuroVive Pharmaceutical        18.07      9.800     3280944
6      Shelton Petroleum B        16.21      3.800     2135798

> head(checkpoint)
                      Firm Gain.Month.1 Last.Price Vol.Month.1 Incep.Price DayCounter
1     Stockwik Förvaltning        87.50       0.06    91270090    0.032000 2016-01-25
2                 Novestra        38.10       7.25      604683    5.249819 2016-01-25
3       Bactiguard Holding        29.09      14.20     2784161   11.000077 2016-01-25
4              MSC Group B        27.56       3.24      657699    2.539981 2016-01-25
5      Shelton Petroleum B        19.27       3.90     1985305    3.269892 2016-01-25
6 NeuroVive Pharmaceutical        16.87       9.70     3220303    8.299820 2016-01-25

> head(left_join(Avanza.XML, checkpoint))
Joining by: c("Firm", "Gain.Month.1", "Last.Price", "Vol.Month.1")
                      Firm Gain.Month.1 Last.Price Vol.Month.1 Incep.Price DayCounter
1     Stockwik Förvaltning       131.25      0.074   131264420          NA       <NA>
2                 Novestra        37.14      7.200      605330          NA       <NA>
3       Bactiguard Holding        29.55     14.250     2815572          NA       <NA>
4              MSC Group B        20.87      3.070      671855          NA       <NA>
5 NeuroVive Pharmaceutical        18.07      9.800     3280944          NA       <NA>
6      Shelton Petroleum B        16.21      3.800     2135798          NA       <NA>
Warning message:
In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector
```

Comment: I think you can join by `Firm` instead of joining by all the columns.  If you look at the values, those values are not matching in `Gain.Month.1` and other columns.

Comment: Doesn't dplyr automatically join by Firm?

Comment: No, you have specify the column in the `by` statement

Comment: The warning is because the column "Firm" is `factor` and have different levels in both the datasets.  You can convert the column to `character` class and there won't be any warning.  i.e. `Avanza.XML <- Avanza.XML %>% mutate(Firm = as.character(Firm))` and similarly for the other dataset, and then do the join.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. Not specifying the `by` argument in `left_join`: In this case, by default all the columns are used as the variables to join by.  If we look at the columns - "Gain.Month.1", "Last.Price",  "Vol.Month.1" - all `numeric` class and do not have a matching value in each of the datasets.  So, it is better to join by "Firm"

   ```
   left_join(Avanza.XML, checkpoint, by = "Firm")
   ```
2. The "Firm" column class - `factor`: We get warning when there is difference in the `levels` of the `factor` column (if it is the variable that we join by).  In order to remove the warning, we can either convert the "Firm" column in both datasets to `character` class

   ```
   Avanza.XML$Firm <- as.character(Avanza.XML$Firm)
   checkpoint$Firm <- as.character(checkpoint$Firm)
   ```

Or if we still want to keep the columns as `factor`, then change the `levels` in the "Firm" to include all the `levels` in both the datasets

```
lvls <- sort(unique(c(levels(Avanza.XML$Firm), 
                          levels(checkpoint$Firm))))
Avanza.XML$Firm <- factor(Avanza.XML$Firm, levels=lvls)
checkpoint$Firm <- factor(checkpoint$Firm, levels=lvls)
```

and then do the `left_join`.