# r dplyr::left_join doesnt match the way I want it

Tags: r, dplyr, left-join

So, this is driving me crazy and I bet the answer is really simple, but I just don't get it. I have two dfs that I want to join, `df1` and `df2`. However, when I perform a `left_join`, the values from the column `Korn` does not get joined on `Datum`, `Soll`, `Plot`, `Behandlung`, `Entfernung`, but instead there are NAs, even though all mentioned columns exist in both dataframes. What am I missing?

```
df1 <- structure(list(Soll = structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("1189", "119", "1192", "1202", "149", 
"172", "2484", "552"), class = "factor"), Datum = structure(c(18725, 
18764, 18815, 18725, 18764, 18815, 18725, 18764, 18815, 18725
), class = "Date"), Plot = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8"), class = "factor"), Behandlung = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    Entfernung = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "5"), class = "factor"), DGUnkraut = c(0.1, 
    4, 12.2, 0.7, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.1), prec = c(2.04, 13.38, 
    121.46, 2.04, 13.38, 121.46, 2.04, 13.38, 121.46, 2.04)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

```
df2 <-structure(list(Soll = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c(" 1189", " 119", " 1202", " 149", " 172", 
" 2484", " 552"), class = "factor"), Datum = structure(c(18815, 
18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815
), class = "Date"), Plot = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8"), class = "factor"), Behandlung = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    Entfernung = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "5"), class = "factor"), Korn = c(65.6, 
    64, 66.4, 57.4, 72.6, 68.9, 68.1, 73.6, 59.9, 34.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

My code:

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(df1, df2) -> df3
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance! Cheers!

Comment: Your factors/levels are different. See `levels(df1$Soll)[1]` and `levels(df2$Soll)[1]` (leading spaces).

Comment: See here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016377/dplyrleft-join-produce-na-values-for-new-joined-columns> @akrun's answer.

Comment: @r2evans I think you are were right. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see here [dplyr::left_join produce NA values for new joined columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35016377/dplyrleft-join-produce-na-values-for-new-joined-columns)

To make your example work. You could:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df2 <- df2 %>%  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(soll = str_trim(soll))

left_join(df1, df2)
```

```
   soll      datum plot behandlung entfernung dg_unkraut   prec korn
1   552 2021-04-08    1          a          2        0.1   2.04   NA
2   552 2021-05-17    1          a          2        4.0  13.38   NA
3   552 2021-07-07    1          a          2       12.2 121.46 64.0
4   552 2021-04-08    1          b          2        0.7   2.04   NA
5   552 2021-05-17    1          b          2        0.0  13.38   NA
6   552 2021-07-07    1          b          2        0.0 121.46 65.6
7   552 2021-04-08    3          a          2        0.2   2.04   NA
8   552 2021-05-17    3          a          2        0.0  13.38   NA
9   552 2021-07-07    3          a          2        0.0 121.46 68.9
10  552 2021-04-08    3          b          2        0.1   2.04   NA
```

Answer (score 3):

As @IanNoriega and @r2evans have mentioned, there is a leading space in `df2`. You can first remove that with `trimws`.

```
df2$Soll <- trimws(df2$Soll)
```

Now, for the join, which works now.

```
dplyr::left_join(df1,
          df2,
          by = c("Soll", "Datum", "Plot", "Behandlung", "Entfernung"))
```

Output

```
   Soll      Datum Plot Behandlung Entfernung DGUnkraut   prec Korn
1   552 2021-04-08    1          a          2       0.1   2.04   NA
2   552 2021-05-17    1          a          2       4.0  13.38   NA
3   552 2021-07-07    1          a          2      12.2 121.46 64.0
4   552 2021-04-08    1          b          2       0.7   2.04   NA
5   552 2021-05-17    1          b          2       0.0  13.38   NA
6   552 2021-07-07    1          b          2       0.0 121.46 65.6
7   552 2021-04-08    3          a          2       0.2   2.04   NA
8   552 2021-05-17    3          a          2       0.0  13.38   NA
9   552 2021-07-07    3          a          2       0.0 121.46 68.9
10  552 2021-04-08    3          b          2       0.1   2.04   NA
```

You could also do it all in one pipe.

```
df1 %>%
  dplyr::left_join(
    .,
    df2 %>% dplyr::mutate(Soll = trimws(Soll)),
    by = c("Soll", "Datum", "Plot", "Behandlung", "Entfernung")
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In your 2nd dataframe, the column `Soll` has a space before the numbers (e.g., " 1189") while this is not the case in your 1st dataframe. Once these are consistent, your left join should work.

To re-generate your 2nd dataframe, see below:

```
df2 <-structure(list(Soll = structure(c(7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L), .Label = c("1189", "119", "1202", "149", "172", 
"2484", "552"), class = "factor"), Datum = structure(c(18815, 
18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815, 18815
), class = "Date"), Plot = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8"), class = "factor"), Behandlung = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), 
    Entfernung = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "5"), class = "factor"), Korn = c(65.6, 
    64, 66.4, 57.4, 72.6, 68.9, 68.1, 73.6, 59.9, 34.6)), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Finally, we can try out our left join. Now we can see actual values of `Korn` appended:

```
joined_df <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2)

   Soll      Datum Plot Behandlung Entfernung DGUnkraut   prec Korn
1   552 2021-04-08    1          a          2       0.1   2.04   NA
2   552 2021-05-17    1          a          2       4.0  13.38   NA
3   552 2021-07-07    1          a          2      12.2 121.46 64.0
4   552 2021-04-08    1          b          2       0.7   2.04   NA
5   552 2021-05-17    1          b          2       0.0  13.38   NA
6   552 2021-07-07    1          b          2       0.0 121.46 65.6
7   552 2021-04-08    3          a          2       0.2   2.04   NA
8   552 2021-05-17    3          a          2       0.0  13.38   NA
9   552 2021-07-07    3          a          2       0.0 121.46 68.9
10  552 2021-04-08    3          b          2       0.1   2.04   NA
```

Comment: This is the right step, but seems an incomplete answer (currently it is really just a comment). Can you demonstrate please?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!